# Positioning of Axis Label in a DateTimeAxis

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, data-visualization

At the moment I have a date time axis where the date is in-line with the points, is there anyway to get this date to appear in the center such as on a bar chart.

[image: Chart Img]

```
<Style x:Key="DateTimeAxisLabelStyle2" TargetType="chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxisLabel">
    <Setter Property="DaysIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:dd-MMM}" />
    <Setter Property="HoursIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:hh:mm tt}" />
    <!--<Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="1,0.5" />
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
       <Setter.Value>
          <RotateTransform Angle="-45" />
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>-->
   <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="30,0,-10,0" />-->
</Style>

<chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis IntervalType="Days"
                               Interval="1"
                               Minimum="{Binding StartDate}"
                               Maximum="{Binding EndDate}"
                               Orientation="X"
                               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                               Title="Day"
                               AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource DateTimeAxisLabelStyle2}" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough, you want to show in the X axis the date in between each two consecutive points  (in addition to the dates in each chart point) ?

Comment: I just want to move the label on the x axis along (into the center), this can be achieved through the use of margins however the x axis is dynamic so using hard coded margins is a no-go. All other data on the graph should remain static

Comment: There is no code behind, the charts itemsSource is brought in via a sp, what are you expecting to see ?

Comment: You can do that, using margin you can shift the label in any direction you wanted, i was just hoping for an easy way to guarantee it is in the center regardless of resizing or data context

Comment: Have you tried using Line Chart ??

Comment: I have not, I assume I would have restructure the data for that to work as it doesn't accept a minimum/maximum on the axis?

Comment: I guess you have two choices to get the render you want : first template/inherit almost every object involved (series and axis), second just insert "fake" (calculated) data between real data (and set Visibility to collapsed for those "fake" X-labels)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what i got:

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DateTimeAxisLabelStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxisLabel}">
        <Setter Property="DaysIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:dd-MMM}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.80,0.20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"></RotateTransform>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Margin="0" Title="Chart Title">
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.DataContext>
            <local:MyDataCollection/>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.DataContext>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis Minimum="{Binding StartDate}" Maximum="{Binding EndDate}" Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="True" AxisLabelStyle="{DynamicResource DateTimeAxisLabelStyle1}"/>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Chart:

[image]

Comment: Hi, appreciate the answer but this does not solve the problem that the chart can be resized or the datacontext could be much larger see ref: [link](https://gyazo.com/e5dd61efb2d74713876f05e878370aca)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did using the [WPF Toolkit Source](https://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) for reference.

I created a custom class deriving from DateTimeAxis, then overrode the "GetPlotAreaCoordinate" method. The DateTimeAxis.Render() calls that method three times with the same list of "DateTime" values, once for the MajorTickmarks, once for MinorTickmarks, and once for the date label. There were no minor tickmarks in the list, so the method was actually only getting called twice. I just keep a list of the values that have been evaluated and assume that if it's in the list it's already done the tickmarks and is now doing the Labels.

```
class CustomDateTimeAxis : DateTimeAxis
{
    List<object> _valueList = new List<object>();
    UnitValue prevBaseValue;

    protected override UnitValue GetPlotAreaCoordinate(object value, Range<IComparable> currentRange, double length)
    {

        _valueList.Add(value);
        UnitValue baseValue = base.GetPlotAreaCoordinate(value, currentRange, length);


        int valueCount = _valueList.Count((x) => x.Equals(value));
        if (valueCount == 2)                       
            return new UnitValue(baseValue.Value + 27, baseValue.Unit);

        prevBaseValue = baseValue;
        return baseValue;

    }

    protected override void Render(Size availableSize)
    {
        base.Render(availableSize);
        _valueList.Clear();
    }

}
```

"27" is just a number I was trying out. You might want to play with that to see what works best for you.

```
return new UnitValue(baseValue.Value + 27, baseValue.Unit);
```

Comment: This appears to just add pixel length to the labels which can be achieved through the use of <Setter Property="Margin" Value="30,0,-10,0" /> in the xaml, is there anyway to guarantee the '27' value is in the center regardless of resizing or data context ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a Margin-Converter:

```
    public class MarginConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dateTimeAxis = values[0] as DateTimeAxis; ;
        var actualAxisLength = values[1] as double?;
        var actualMaximum = values[2] as DateTime?;
        var actualMinimum = values[3] as DateTime?;

        if (dateTimeAxis == null || 
            !dateTimeAxis.Interval.HasValue || 
            !actualAxisLength.HasValue || 
            !actualMaximum.HasValue || 
            !actualMinimum.HasValue)
            return null;

        double xMargin = 0;

        var interval = dateTimeAxis.Interval.Value;

        var timeSpan = actualMaximum.Value - actualMinimum.Value;
        var timeSpanInDays = timeSpan.TotalDays;

        if (dateTimeAxis.IntervalType == DateTimeIntervalType.Months)
        {
            xMargin = 30 * interval * actualAxisLength.Value / timeSpanInDays;
        }
        else if (dateTimeAxis.IntervalType == DateTimeIntervalType.Days)
        {
            xMargin = interval * actualAxisLength.Value / timeSpanInDays;
        }

        return new Thickness(xMargin, 10, 0, -30);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, System.Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

called the X-Axis 'SharedXAxis' and used the converter like this:

```
<Setter Property="Margin">
<Setter.Value>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MarginConv}">
        <Binding ElementName="SharedXAxis"/>
        <Binding ElementName="SharedXAxis" Path="ActualWidth"/>
        <Binding ElementName="SharedXAxis" Path="ActualMaximum"/>
        <Binding ElementName="SharedXAxis" Path="ActualMinimum"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Setter.Value>
```

Imo this should be full dynamic. 
The Top- and Bottom-Values of the Thickness of the Margin-Converter ('10' and '-30' in my case) as well as the Bottom-Value of the Padding of the Chart itself have to be adjusted, I don't know why.